# What does it mean if you have a hanger on your profile pic?

Tags: family-guy-the-quest-for-stuff

After unlocking Bonnie in [Quest for Stuff](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tinyco.familyguy) you can view her profile on FaceSpace.  In her profile picture, there is a hanger with a red banner under it.

Does this mean anything?  I've unlocked Peter, Chris, and Quagmire, but none of them have the icon either.

[image: Bonnie Profile FaceSpace]

Comment: +1 for asking a question in which "hanger" is not a misspelling of "hangar".

Comment: [An Achievement. They are usually involved in getting a characters outfit built.](http://familyguyaddicts.com/help-me/questions-and-answers/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the hanger means that you have unlocked all available outfits for that character.